# How to print all letters (a to z) in objective c using NSString

Tags: objective-c

I have created NSString instance and using that instance how to print all letters separately.

I am new to IOS...Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have written a program for you which will print all alphabets in NSString.

```
    int a = 65;
    NSString *strAlphabets;
    for (; a < 91; a++) {
        if(strAlphabets){
    strAlphabets = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %c",strAlphabets,(char)a];
    }else{
        strAlphabets = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c",(char)a];
    }
    }
    NSLog(@"%@", strAlphabets);
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for helping me out.

Answer (score 2):

**If you log all the letter a to z then you can use:**

```
 for (char c = 'a'; c <= 'z'; c++) {
    NSString *firstLetter = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c", c];
NSLog("%@",firstLetter);
}
```

Comment: I did it, Thank you.

Comment: @AbhilashGupta Your welcome, If my answer helpful for you then please give it to correct mark. This will be helpful for other developer and users.

Answer (score 0):

But if you want to print all letters in NSString than use these:

```
NSString *string = @"abcd";
for (NSUInteger index = 0; index < string.length; index++) {
    unichar letter = [string characterAtIndex:index];
    NSLog(@"%c", letter);

}
```